# IBL probe BRDF pre-integration artifacts

Tags: opengl

I'm following '[Moving Frostbite to PBR course notes](http://www.frostbite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/course_notes_moving_frostbite_to_pbr_v2.pdf)' to implement IBL in my rendering engine in OpenGL but I'm having some trouble pre-integrating the specular component of the equation.

As you'll see from my next images, the problem is visible in the mipmaps of the cubemap result of the pre-filtered importance sampling.

This is the positive X face mip chain:
[image]

This is the negative X face mip chain:
[image]

This is the environment map I use (it is dynamically created physically based sky texture in an HDR format):
[image]

This is the positive X face mip chain of the environment map:
[image]

As you can see, on the right side of the mips of the positive X face seems like the sampling direction goes similar to the sampling direction of the left side of the mip.

Also, there are those 'dot-like' shapes visible on the second mip of the positive X face that I think are due to a low amount of samples maybe?

This is the code I use to pre-integrate the specular IBL:

```
float radicalInverse_VdC(uint bits)
{
    bits = (bits << 16u) | (bits >> 16u);
    bits = ((bits & 0x55555555u) << 1u) | ((bits & 0xAAAAAAAAu) >> 1u);
    bits = ((bits & 0x33333333u) << 2u) | ((bits & 0xCCCCCCCCu) >> 2u);
    bits = ((bits & 0x0F0F0F0Fu) << 4u) | ((bits & 0xF0F0F0F0u) >> 4u);
    bits = ((bits & 0x00FF00FFu) << 8u) | ((bits & 0xFF00FF00u) >> 8u);
    return float(bits) * 2.3283064365386963e-10; // / 0x100000000
}

//
// Attributed to:
// http://holger.dammertz.org/stuff/notes_HammersleyOnHemisphere.html
// Holger Dammertz.
// 
vec2 Hammersley(uint i, uint N) 
{
    return vec2(float(i)/float(N), radicalInverse_VdC(i));
}

// Based on GGX example in:
// http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/s2013-shading-course/karis/s2013_pbs_epic_notes_v2.pdf
vec3 importanceSampleGGX(vec2 u, float roughness, vec3 N, vec3 upVector, vec3 tangentX, vec3 tangentY)
{
    float a = roughness * roughness;

    float phiH = u.x * PI * 2.0f;
    float cosThetaH = sqrt((1.0f - u.y) / (1.0f + (a * a - 1.0f) * u.y));
    float sinThetaH = sqrt(1.0f - min(1.0f, cosThetaH * cosThetaH));

    vec3 H = vec3(sinThetaH * cos(phiH), sinThetaH * sin(phiH), cosThetaH);
    H = normalize(tangentX * H.x + tangentY * H.y + N * H.z);
    return H;
}

// D(h) for GGX.
// http://graphicrants.blogspot.com/2013/08/specular-brdf-reference.html
float D_GGX(float roughness, float NdotH)
{
    float a = roughness * roughness;
    float a2 = a * a;
    float NdotH2 = NdotH * NdotH;
    float f = 1.0f + (NdotH2 * (a2 - 1.0f));
    return a2 / (f * f);
}

float D_GGX_Divide_Pi(float roughness, float NdotH)
{
    return D_GGX(roughness, NdotH) / PI;
}

vec3 ImportanceSample (vec3 N)
{
    vec3 V = N;

    float size2 = ConvolutionSrcSize * ConvolutionSrcSize; 
    vec3 upVector = abs(N.z) < 0.999 ? vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) : vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    vec3 tangentX = normalize(cross(upVector, N));
    vec3 tangentY = cross(N, tangentX);

    vec3 accBrdf = vec3(0.0f);
    float accBrdfWeight = 0.0f;
    float roughness = ConvolutionRoughness;

    uint samplesCount = uint(ConvolutionSampleCount);
    for(uint i = uint(0); i < samplesCount; i++)
    {
        vec2 eta = Hammersley(i, samplesCount);

        vec3 H = importanceSampleGGX(eta, roughness, N, upVector, tangentX, tangentY);
        vec3 L = 2.0f * dot(V, H) * H - V;
        float NdotL = dot(N, L);

        if(NdotL > 0.0f)
        {
            float NdotH = saturate(dot(N, H));
            float LdotH = saturate(dot(L, H));
            float pdf = D_GGX_Divide_Pi(roughness, NdotH) * NdotH / (4.0f * LdotH);

            float omegaS = 1.0f / (samplesCount * pdf);
            float omegaP = 4.0f * PI / (6.0f * size2);

            float mipLevel = roughness == 0.0f ? 0.0f : clamp(0.5f * log2(omegaS / omegaP), 0.0f, ConvolutionMipCount);

            vec4 Li = textureLod(ConvolutionSrc, L, mipLevel);

            accBrdf += Li.rgb * NdotL;
            accBrdfWeight += NdotL;
        }
    }

    if(accBrdfWeight > 0.0f)
        return accBrdf * (1.0f / accBrdfWeight);
    else
        return accBrdf;
}

void main()
{
    // VertexIn.textureCoord is the normal of a sphere I use as mesh to draw to the IBL cubemap
    FragColor = vec4(ImportanceSample(VertexIn.textureCoord), 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was due to the cubemap seam problem near the cube faces edges. Enabling `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS` solved the problem. I didn't notice this since I use NSight to debug the shaders but NSight doesn't support `glTexParameteri` with `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS` so I always disabled it to debug the shaders but I found out that NSight accepts `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS)`.

One problem remains though, the mips are very very noisy, also with a huge amount of samples. With 1024 samples I get this:

[image]